# Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on FakeRAID Installation error - question marks "????..."

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on FakeRAID along Win7.

Win 7 has been already installed, and dmraid is running.

During the installation I choose to manually partition, this is the structure:

```
\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0
\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0Op1 - NTFS Win7 loader
\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0Op2 - NTFS Win7 partition
\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0Op3 - swap
\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0Op5 - ext4 mounted as \
\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0Op6 - ext4 mounted as \home
```

There is another sequence similar to above marked as "linear".

I choose `\dev\mapper\isw_gchdghhd_Volume0` as boot device.

When immediately after the installation begins, an error with question marks pops up, and the installation stops.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the issue:

`dmraid` was replaced by `mdadm` for handling FakeRAID in Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's the solution:

1. Boot the installation disk and choose *Try Ubuntu*.
2. Connect to the internet. (**crucial step, you need to install from the repository.**)
3. Open terminal and type the following:

   ```
   sudo dmraid -a n
   sudo apt-get install mdadm
   ```

   This will disable `dmraid` and install `mdadm`.
4. You will be prompted with postfix configuration, chose *No Configuration*.
5. To automatically recognize your FakeRAID, run:

   ```
   sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
   ```
6. Run the installer.
7. Choose *Install Ubuntu*.
8. Choose to partition *manually* and create an EXT4 partition mounted as `\` and a SWAP partition.
9. When choosing where to write the Boot-Loader, Choose the volume mounted as "/".
10. Proceed with the installation. *Note: The installer will fail to write GRUB.*
11. Reboot the installation disk and choose *Try Ubuntu* again.
12. Connect to the internet.
13. Install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and run it. It will guide you on fixing the boot loader and rewriting GRUB.

This might be long, but it worked for me. I now have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot configuration.

Comment: This answer solved my problem after hours of effort. I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 7 on an Intel Rapid Storage Technology Fake RAID. When the installer failed to write GRUB, it stopped responding and I had to kill it, but at that point it had done enough that I could continue the remaining steps. It works fine now.