# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop install stuck in loop at Where Are You

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit Desktop.  I'm using all defaults and after accepting "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" I click the "Install Now" button.  Immediately, the "Where are you?" form comes up with a small error window showing "??? ???" in both the error window's text and header.  The pointer is still active.  The "Continue" button seems to be active but ignores clicks.  I can't click anywhere on the entire screen with the exception of the "OK" button in the error window.  Once I click that I'm taken back to the previous "Install Now" button.  Seems like I'm stuck in a loop.
Thanks,
Curt

i5
Asus Z97-ar mobo
16GB RAM
2 x 4TB hard drives

Comment: My best guess is that the install disk is corrupted or that it is a very uncommon and strange bug.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am fairly certain that the install DVD I am using is solid.  Looks to me like an uncommon bug.  Especially strange that I just get "??? ???" instead of a meaningful message in the error window.

Comment: This may be the same problem as [Ubuntu 14.04 not installing, popup error ??? at “where are you?”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/504055/ubuntu-14-04-not-installing-popup-error-at-where-are-you) or [Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on FakeRAID Installation error - question marks “????…”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m)

Answer (score 1):

My Ubuntu 14.04 installation hung when I entered Montreal in response to the question, "Where are you?". When I entered, New York, which is in the same time zone as Montreal, the the installation proceeded normally.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your install disk is corrupted.

I recommend you reacquire the install .iso [from the Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and this time double-check the md5sum hash of the downloaded file with the given hash on the site.

Assuming that the hash is valid, you should then proceed to burn the .iso to cd/usb and then restart the install process with the new install media.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.  The md5 of the downloaded file matches the value given on the Ubuntu download site.  Additionally, I created an iso from the DVD I burned just to make sure that nothing was lost in the burning process and that md5 also matched the original iso.  So, I'm fairly confident that I am working with a good install DVD.  The only out of the ordinary with the machine might be that I have 2 x 4TB SATA drives in RAID 1 configuration.  Can't imagine how that might affect the install though.  Thank you again.

Comment: Try the manual partition version, see how far you can get and report back here if it doesn't work out (same issue).

Answer (score -1):

Try enabling LVM. It may work for you.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer by editing, to explain why using LVM might fix the problem here. Is the idea to use it as an alternative to RAID?