# New install with unknown error (??? ???)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a brand-new (Shuttle) computer. I have tried installing Ubuntu three different ways so far. Each time, at the point it creates mount points (whether I do it manually or let it create them automatically) it goes to the window to choose the location. At this point an error screen called "??? ???" comes up, with an error of "??? ???". The only choice is to hit "OK" . . . which just brings it back.

This is a system I'm setting up to dual-boot with Windows 7 (also a new install).

I did already look at [Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on FakeRAID Installation error - question marks "????..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m), even though I am installing the boot partition to a single SSD drive. However during the first step, it says that the config file is locked and the install had an error. I would be surprised if mine is the same issue, though.

Comment: It doesn't look like the same problem I have, his is an issue with FakeRAID. In my case both the boot loader and the "/" partition are on the boot drive (an SSD directly on the motherboard). The "/home" is on a RAID drive, but it is hardware raid and I don't think that it should make a difference.

Comment: If you have external hard unplug it and try again.

Comment: There is no external hard drive. Just booting off CD, internal SSD drive.

I did attempt the instructions for the FakeRAID comment, but it gets an error saying that the config file is locked and it won't run the first step. I thought that I would give it a shot just in case.

The boot drive is a SSD drive installed on a MINI PCI card, but I would assume that wouldn't affect it this way.

Comment: No Idea. just I removed comments. and you, please edit your question and add this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m that you tried but had no luck.