# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with hardware RAID

Tags: 14.04, raid, mdadm

I have been having some issues with trying to install Ubuntu off of a live usb. The system has a Intel hardware RAID controller and I wish to run my two HDDs in RAID 1. I have come across and issue when running the installer. There seems to be a ??? ??? prompt with the repitition of ??? ??? which appears after the language/region is set.

From what I have read there seems to be some issue with RAID and Ubuntu 14? The only solution I seem to have found is to install mdadm and create a software RAID configuration. But i am guessing a hardware raid would be better as I have the card?

Can't remember the exact model of the intel RAID card, will update once I have gotten back to the office.

Any one have any solutions? will check against the compatibility pages once I can get back to the computer to check the RAID card model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have hardware raid.  Hardware raid involves expensive add on cards, or high end server motherboards.  The raid support in consumer level intel chipsets is known as fake raid, because it is really software raid masquerading as hardware.  It does not work all that well, especially in linux.  Avoid it if you don't have to dual boot with windows, which has terrible software raid support ( which is the whole reason these fakeraids exist ).  You also should file a bug report against the ubiquity package and attach /var/log/syslog after getting this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on FakeRAID Installation error - question marks "????..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m)

Comment: Did you look into `mdadm`

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this on an HP server with an internal raid controller. It was listed as supported on all the HP and Ubuntu hardware matrices, but it turns out that the controller was only supported on Windows, not Linux.

However, if you have a hardware RAID controller, do you see a prompt when the system POSTs (power on self test), saying something like "Intel storage array configuration. Press F4", or some such message? You would press that function key to get into the array configuration software resident on the controller, BEFORE the Ubuntu installation even starts.

In that config utility, you would setup your two disks as a RAID1 "logical volume". Then, when you go to install Ubuntu, this logical volume would be listed as the disk device upon which you would install Linux.

The caveat is that if Ubuntu does NOT support that RAID controller, the logical volume will not be recognized. That's what happened on my HP server.

So I had to delete the logical volume (in the raid controller software), then create a software RAID set in the server version of Ubuntu (this isn't available in the desktop version). There is a really good tutorial on the Ubuntu doc set for setting up software raid (using mdadm).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to avoid it is install lubuntu (the desktop  choice isn’t an issue for me, its running as a webserver).  Seems like it is the RAID and the graphics driver or some weirdness, because if I do get it installed in lubuntu  and I run additional drivers and install a compatible graphics driver it locks up bad again.  (I had used to use classic gnome install on previous installs on this machine but that is gone now)  This was a HP minitower with built-in RAID.

So if you are at your wits end, try an lubuntu install and see if it works for you too.  Tried xubuntu too and that didn't work, lubuntu is the one to try.