# Error while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb-installation

I have problem while installing Ubuntu 14.04. I described it on imgur.com, cause I had to add a lot of pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPeDm.jpg

Pic with error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RWhC5xH.jpg]

Generally this error occures after choosing partitions and I don't know how to make it works. I was trying about 6 times and always the same. I'm installing from USB pendrive, cause I have Asus UX51Vz, that doesn't have CD-ROM.

Comment: windows 8 can be tricky, you may find the answer you need by searching on the topic of installing ubuntu on a windows8 computer.

Comment: Unfortunately this bug has *still* not been solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on FakeRAID Installation error - question marks "????..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m)

Comment: Thanks @muru for answer I'm going to try this and I will report back if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me.