# Rebuild RST Fake RAID 5 on Ubuntu Windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, raid, mdadm, rst

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a second OS on a computer which had Windows 7 already installed. The computer had an Intel RST FakeRAID level 5. After a good deal of messing around, I finally followed the instructions in the top answer to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m) This worked fine... until one of my hard drives failed.

I replaced the drive, and booted into Windows, where I rebuilt the RAID volume with Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

Now Windows boots and functions perfectly fine, but Ubuntu hangs while booting.

What's going on, and how can I fix this? According to [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005769/technologies.html), mdadm is supposed to be able to handle Intel RST.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to boot into recovery mode, and it dropped me to the initramfs shell, after telling me that fsck had found errors on my last partition.

Because I suspected that the RAID format used by the Intel RST tool in Windows was different from the RAID format used by mdadm in Linux, I was afraid to repair the filesystem with fsck. But after I had verified that the raid had been detected correctly, I finally ran fsck on the last partition. This solved the problem.